# Make a complex css grid

Tags: html, css, grid

I'm about to become insane with this css thing. I don't know the language very well..and can't make what I need to do.

I have this html

```
<div id="content">      
    <div id="video-content">
        <div id="source">
            <div id="s-video">
            </div>
            <div id="source-controls">
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="preview"> 
            <div id="p-video">
            </div>
            <div id="preview-controls">
            </div>
        </div>      
    </div>

    <div id="segment-content">
        <ul>
            <li></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have to achieve this:

[image]

so far my css code:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/
  /*color: #666;*/
   background: #141414; 
  /*font-size: 1em;*/
  /*line-height: 1.5em;*/
}

#content {
 background: dimgrey;
 width: 97%;
 height: 90%;
 position: fixed;
 top: 0;
 right: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 left: 0;
 margin: auto;
}

#video-content {
  background-color: #7F7F7F;
  position: fixed;
  width: 300px;
  z-index: 20;
}

 #segment-content {
   background-color: #7F7F7F;
   position: fixed;
   width: 300px;
 }
```

I am not interested in doing this resposive so far

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get a clean grid you'll have to change your html-structure a little bit.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="video-content">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div id="source"></div>
      <div id="s-video">
      </div>
      <div id="source-controls">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-1-2">
      <div id="preview">
        <div id="p-video">
        </div>
        <div id="preview-controls">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-1-1">
      <div id="segment-content">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here's an example I made of how to achieve something similar to your screenshot:
[Codepen example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/advOaM)

You want to switch out the height-properties or remove them completly and let the content fill in dynamically. I used them in this example since we have no content, so that the divs become visible.

Comment: thanks! how can I apply this to the entire page dimensions?

Comment: Simply change the width of the #content from 500px to 100% (updated my codepen example). But like one of the other answers already mentioned, you are probably better off using a framework. Also, don't use ids unless you need a unique identifier (for example for accessing it with javascript)

Answer (score 0):

```
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  /*font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;*/
  /*color: #666;*/
   background: #141414; 
   height:auto;
  /*font-size: 1em;*/
  /*line-height: 1.5em;*/
}

#content{width:100%;
height:auto;
background: dimgrey;}

#video-content{width:80%;
height:370px;
margin:0 auto;}

#source{width:45%;
float:left;
height:auto;
}

#preview{width:45%;
float:left;
height:auto;
margin-left:10%;
}

#s-video{width:100%;
height:300px;
background-color:black;}


#p-video{width:100%;
height:300px;
background-color:black;}

#source-controls{width:100%;
height:50px;
background:red;
margin-top:20px;}

#preview-controls{width:100%;
height:50px;
background:red;
margin-top:20px;}

#segment-content:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;}

#segment-content{width:80%;
margin: 20px auto;
height:300px;
background:blue;}
```

this will work,although not the pretty way of writing css

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be much better off going with a pre-built framework if that's an option.  Something like purecss.io or bootstrap. But this should also work for what you want.

https://jsfiddle.net/w5qfvezg/

```
.video-display {
  background-color: black;
  min-height: 200px;
}

.video-description {
  background-color: red;
  min-height: 50px;
}

body {
  padding: 5%;
  padding-left: 10%;
  padding-right: 10%;
  background-color: #999;
}

.video-item {
  width: 49%;
  float: left;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.video-spacer {
  width: 2%;
  float: left;
  min-height: 200px;
}

#segment-content {
  background-color: blue;
  min-height: 200px;
}


<body>
  <div id='video-content'>
    <div class='video-item' id='source'>
      <div class='video-display' id="s-video">
      </div>
      <div class='video-description' id="source-controls">
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='video-spacer'>
    </div>
    <div class='video-item' id='preview'>
      <div class='video-display' id='p-video'>
      </div>
      <div class='video-description' id="preview-controls">
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style='clear:both'>
  </div>
  <div id="segment-content">
    <ul>
      <li></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>
```